# MVC4 site Mono 3.2.1 ubuntu 13.04 Nginx Mobile Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ubuntu, nginx, mono

I have setup a production server running mono 3.2.1 built from github, and nginx.
Everything is working fine, regular subdomains, and my monoserved mvc4 site.
I have also switched to unix sockets instead of tcp because I was noticing some strange behaviour in terms of ram usage.

So far - I am using only 10% of the system resources I was using on my windows VPS with the same configuration, so linux hosted mvc is like discovering sliced bread for the first time :D

However, I get a NotImplementedException error when trying the following:

In my Global.asax.cs file, after the bundling setup under Application_Start()
I am registering or at least trying to register checks to see if its a mobile device and thus serve my Index.Mobile.cshtml

Like So

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iphone")
        {
            ContextCondition = Context =>
                            Context.Request.Browser["HardwareModel"] == "iPhone"
        });

        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(1, new DefaultDisplayMode("android")
        {
            ContextCondition = Context =>
                            Context.Request.Browser["PlatformName"] == "Android"
        });

        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(2, new DefaultDisplayMode("mobile")
        {
            ContextCondition = Context =>
                            Context.Request.Browser["IsMobile"] == "True"
        });

    }
```

As far as I have found, is in the aspnetwebstack in mono, there is DisplayModeProvider
(i.e.)

```
https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/DisplayModeProvider.cs
```

But If I have those lines in my Global.asax.cs I get the error stating its not implemented when I try to load the page (with  in my webconfig)

Can anyone point me in the right direction as I need this site to serve different pages to mobiles :)

Many Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 1):

All is well now.

I have changed how I added them to the DisplayModeProvider.

It works fine if I do it as follows:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
                                                  {
            ContextCondition = (ctx =>
                                ctx.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("iPad", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                                ctx.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                                ctx.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Windows Phone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
                                ctx.Request.UserAgent.Contains("Mobile Safari")||
                                ctx.Request.UserAgent.Contains("Android") &&
                                ctx.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("Mobile", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) <= 0
                                )
        });
```